# Ruby On Rails: Testing deletes tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I'm creating an application in RoR and I'm implementing unit testing in all my models.

When I run every test on his own (by running ruby test/unit/some_test.rb) all tests are successful.

But when I run all tests together (by running rake test:units) some tables from both databases (development e test) are deleted.

I'm using raw SQL (mysql) do create tables because I need composite primary keys and physical constraints so I figured it would be the best. Maybe this be the cause?

All my tests are in this form:

> require File.dirname(**FILE**) + '/../test_helper'
>   require File.dirname(**FILE**) + '/../../app/models/order'
>
> class OrderTestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase
>
> def setup
>
> ```
> @order = Order.new(
>     :user_id => 1,
>     :total => 10.23,
>     :date => Date.today,
>     :status => 'processing',
>     :date_concluded => Date.today,
>     :user_address_user_id => 3,
>     :user_address_address_id => 5,
>     :creation_date => Date.today,
>     :update_date => Date.today
>   )
> ```
>
> end
>
> ################ Happy Path
>
> def test_happy_path
>
> assert @order.valid?, @order.errors.full_messages
>
> end
>   ...

The errors I get when running the tests are something like this:

3) Error:
test_empty_is_primary(AddressTestCase):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'shopshop_enterprise_test.addresses' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `addresses`
    /test/unit/address_test.rb:9:in `new'
    /test/unit/address_test.rb:9:in`setup'

Any guesses?
Thanks!

PS: When using postgres as the database engine, everything works fine with rake test:units! (of course, with the correct changes so the sql statements can work with postgres)

Comment: Your error is for an address_test, yet you are showing the order test code?  you sure you cut and pasted the right error over?